# Use new hosting which is already used buy a domain, for a new domain

Tags: web-hosting, domains

I am new to web hosting n stuffs,

I am having a domain called www.yassershaikh.com from domainz.in, from where I had taken a LINUX hosting. I am running a wordpress blog there.

Now I have taken a another domain from goDaddy called www.codera.org, now here I want to use Windows hosting, but that I am not planning to buy for atleast 6 months.

So I was thinking if it's possible to use the hosting(LINUX) which I am using for my first site.

Is this possible ? Please guide me on this please.

(Also for now I am just redirecting it to one page on my blog.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your domainz.in plan allows you to host multiple websites from one account, you can definitely do that.

Some general steps can be followed for the same:

1. Navigate to the add website zone in your hosting account (you have to search for it, if it is available)
2. When asked to register a domain or to enter a name to host, just enter the name and select the option that says that domain is already registered.
3. Do remember to enter your webhost's nameservers into the nameservers for the registered domain in your godaddy account. (This is done to handle dns queries properly). (AFAIK, it is present in the same window where you can set up redirects in godaddy, just check and you'll find it easily)
4. From here onwards, the steps are general enough to setup any website, whether it's setting up a wordpress blog or any other.

For example, in my case (using bluehost) i have options to add registered domains to my current account as depicted in the image:
[image: Add registered domains]

I would then select "Assign a domain to your cPanel account" and follow the above listed steps.

Comment: HI, I just checked my cPanel, I dont see option for "Add Website", under which tab/option can I find it ?

Comment: @Yasser You may not find it in Cpanel. It should be available in your hosting account separately (in my case it's under "Domain Manager"). See the image in the post above.

Comment: @Yasser: In cPanel it is usually called "Addon Domains" (in the Domains section) - but as suggested above, this will only be available if your hosting provider allows you to host multiple domains on the one account.

Comment: Under "Domain Manager", I clicked the `Click Here To Update Name Servers` and boom, my first website is not working now :(, the `Addon Domain` thing, man if I had only known this first. YES my host allows me to host multiple domains.